# Can I prevent Administrators from Updating Modules?

Tags: updating

So I had an issue yesterday where a module was updated on one of my sites that I wasn't ready for it to be updated on.  It caused some issues, but I was eventually able to get the previous version back from my test server and it is working normally again.

My guess is that someone with administrative rights (but not User-1) was able to update the module from the web interface.  Is there a way to prevent anyone from updating modules except User-1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck the permissions "administer software updates" from roles, and they should no longer have access to this screen in the admin.

At the same time, it is advised to use drush or other methods of applying updates, as the admin screen is pretty not great for this.

Comment: Plus there's a strong argument that the Update module itself shouldn't even be enabled on a production site

Comment: Yeah, I never use the web interface to apply the updates myself.  The administrators don't have access to the server, hence why it was probably done from the web interface is my guess.

And thank you, I guess I skimmed the permissions too quickly and didn't see that setting :)